# How to perform a convergence test of Runge-Kutta numerical integration

Tags: computational-physics

I've come across multiple assignments now where I am to calculate trajectories, orbits etc. using the Runge-Kutta 4th order method.
However, each time I am also asked to perform the correct convergence tests to make sure that I have a valid time step for my method.

What exactly am I looking for when performing the convergence test? And how would I do this for numerical methods where I can't compare with analytic results?

Comment: This question would probably be a better fit for [computational science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If resources are not limited, you can just run the algorithm twice with a different step size. The $L^1$ distance (or any other norm) between the solutions is a good estimate of the error. There are much better approaches, but this one is conceptually very simple.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on scicomp.stackexchange.

Comment: Orbits with RK4!? You may want tolook into *symplectic integrators*.

Comment: I discuss convergence wrt PDEs [in this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/311969/25301). It may be of use to your situation (but not a dupe).