# Tipler & Mosca on "accuracy"

Tags: computational-physics, error-analysis

In the Tipler & Mosca textbook we are shown how numerical integration (the Euler's method species of it) is done using a spreadsheet program. The authors then go on to say on page 138 that the accuracy of this program can be estimated by first calculating the values for a time interval of 0.5s, then repeating this for a time interval of 0.25s and comparing the values obtained for the two intervals.

I believe that the second interval is arbitrary and the authors simply chose it as an example. It seems that any interval which is small compared to the first one would be sufficient. I think that the purpose of the second run of the program using the "small" interval is basically to mimick what the values would look like if the interval tends to zero. Thus by comparing the original interval to this "zero" interval, we can estimate the accuracy of the original interval with the "actual" values of the variables.

Am I interpreting this correctly?

Edit: The passage in question is the second paragraph on the second page here (the one starting "but how accurate..."):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ltkcj6wcayd6m7v/tipler%20mosc%20accuracy.pdf?dl=0

Comment: I answered a similar question about the number of grid points in a PDE [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/311969/25301) & the error; it maybe useful for you.

Comment: @KyleKanos: I am only seeking a quick explanation of what the authors mean by their small note on accuracy and whether I have interpreted it correctly. I will attach a screenshot of the passage.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is not accuracy ... it's round-off error.  Numbers in a computer memory are only accurate based on the number of bits that the computer's memory uses to represent them.  For example, if a measurement with a range of 0-8 is represented in the computer's memory by 3 bits, that number can be any integer from 0-7, but it cannot be 2.55 or 3.56 because there are not enough bits to represent such a number.  Admittedly, this is a ridiculous example, but common numeric representations use 32 bits to represent a number in memory, and even with this number of bits, there are "gaps" in the numbers that can be represented, and the computer memory is not truly continuous when numeric data is stored in memory.

Another issue is the fact that numeric integration necessarily requires a Riemann sum approach.  When using Riemann sums, more and more accuracy is obtained as the width of the associated rectangles approaches zero.  Naturally, this means that the number of rectangles in the sum approaches infinity as the width approaches zero.

The two issues above are "competing".  The accuracy of your answer increases as the time interval noted above gets smaller, but only to a point.  As the time interval gets smaller and smaller, the round-off error becomes more prominent.  Due to this, the authors recommended a comparison of several different time intervals, which should produce a pattern whereby you can estimate the time interval that gives the best combination of Riemann sum accuracy and acceptable round-off error.